# Cost of Inheritance Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, python, performance, inheritance

I am building an extension of ORMLite to target Android.

**What I want to do**

I want to reproduce one of the behavior that Doctrine and Symfony are achieving in PHP with models.
In a word:

- From a yml file generate a bunch of BaseModel class with accessors
  and things that won't change.
- Let the real model inherits from this
  BaseModel so that the user changes could persist even if they regenerate the models from the yml.

**My question**

I was wondering if this is good in practice to try to achieve such an objective on Android or if this will be risky in terms of performance (the heavy usage of inheritance).

If you think that it is clumsy, how can I allow the user to change the .yml file, generate the model and do no start from scratch rebuilding the customized aspects of his model.
I know this can be done by some "trick" but I really would like not to reinvent the wheel.

### EDIT

Sorry, I forgot to add: **I am using python** to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the correct, and probably only, Java way. In Java all calls are virtual anyway unless you use `final` all over the place, but that means you couldn't even use interfaces. So most calls will probably be virtual dispatch whatever you do. Inheritance does not incur any other significant penalty.

Besides, Android devices are generally so powerful that trying to sqeeze out tiny bits of performance at the cost of readability and maintainability of the program is almost certainly not needed. In fact, most android devices are almost as powerful as web servers that do the same things in much slower PHP and still manage thousands of users while the Android device serves one.

Comment: Yeah, I know that but how much will it cost to do the method resolution compared to a standard method resolution (without inheritance)? Is it gonna impact the performance or is it out of purpose to think that it will do so?

Comment: @lc2817: All dispatch in Java is virtual and it does not matter whether the method is overloaded or not.

Comment: why do you talk about overloading? So you mean that inheritance has no cost except a small memory overhead?

Comment: So basically you think that it is useless to pay attention to the cost of inheritance in that case since it is negligible in front of the other factor?

Comment: @lc2817: Yes. Inheritance has no cost except memory to store the metaclasses and code. The call simply goes to the actual meta-class of the instance and picks the right method there. If the method comes from base class, it is resolved at load time or maybe at first call, but certainly not each time. In contrast dynamic languages like python or php that do search the class hierarchy each time.

Comment: @lc2817: Yes, I do think the cost of inheritance is negligible compared to other factors. Besides you can't really tell what those factors will be until you implement and profile it. So you should only care to avoid using excessively complex algorithms on non-trivial datasets and leave everything else until you have working implementation and actually find that you really need to speed it up.